# html transition of 5 images, stop the last image

Tags: transition

Gooh night, I have a transition of 5 images that change automatically, I need that when I get to image 5 it stays fixed and does not repeat the transition. 
that is to say that when the 5 images pass it remains fixed in the last Thank you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:800px">
  <img class="mySlides" id="img1" src="1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" id="img2" src="2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" id="img3" src="3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" id="img4" src="4.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" id="img5" src="5.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(carousel, 500); // Change image every 2 seconds


}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are going back to the first one with `if(myIndex>x.length) myIndex=1;`. Instead, if `myIndex` is the las item, don't even call `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Thanks, but I did not understand how to solve it.

Comment: It's repeating the animation because you're telling so. Remove the line that goes back to the beginning. And only call `setTimeout(...)` if you are not in the last slide. I.e. `if(myIndex<x.length) setTimeout(carousel,500);`. In other words, if you are in the last slide, you gotta stop.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it may help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<style>
.mySlides {display:none;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_la.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_ny.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="img_chicago.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    clearTimeout(carousel);
    x[myIndex-2].style.display = "block";
  }    
  x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(carousel, 500); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Akshay, Thank you so much.

Comment: If you satisfy with this answer then mark it as correct and vote up for this.